move files between two folders in a GCS bucket
I have a DAG task like this:
 move_files = GCSToGCSOperator(
    task_id='move_files',
    impersonation_chain='service_account',
    source_bucket='ingestion_bucket',
    source_object='ABCD/Daily_data*.csv',
    destination_bucket='ingestion_bucket',
    destination_object='ABCD/loaded_files',
    move_object=True
)

I have a folder named "ABCD" in the 'ingestion_bucket' and a folder named "loaded_files" in the "ABCD" folder. I need to read files named "Daily_data*.csv" through a sensor, perform some processes and then move them to the loaded_files folder.
Wehenever the task runs, it creates another folder named "loaded_files" in the "loaded_files" folder and so on... after a while the task gets exahausted and doesnt move the files and reingest them again...
the error is
google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 POST storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/ingestion_bucket/o/ABCD%2Floaded_files%2Floaded_files%2Floaded_files%2Floaded_files%2Floaded_files%2Floaded_files%2Floaded_files%2Floaded_files%2Floaded_files%2Floaded_files%2Floaded_files%2Floaded_files%2Fl..
Is there any solution for that?

have you tried without the .csv part after your wildcard ?

@vdolez I removed the .csv and it worked perfectly! I am curious what is a difference between Daily_data*.csv and Daily_data*? In the first case, I had a folder named "loaded_files" and nested folders were created at each run ,files also were renamed to loaded_files_Daily_data*.csv (at each run the path was added to the file name so that the file which was ingested in the third run was loaded_files_loaded_files_Daily_data*.csv) ... In the second form, I didnt need any folder and after ingestion, the file was renamed to loaded_files*.csv.

I think the wildcard is interpreted only at the end of the string, and can not be handled in the middle of a string. Just a guess though.

hmmm, I think, it handled that, but in a different way... Thank you so much by the way, your solution solved my problem!
